# Proper way to express the time of a flight

Tags: traducción

I need to say "My flight is at 10".  I can imagine several translations:

> Mi vuelo esta a las 10.
>
> Mi vuelo es a las 10.
>
> Mi vuelo sale a las 10.
>
> Yo vuelo a las 10.

Are any of these close to being correct?

Answer (score 11):

Except for the first one, all of them are correct. I'd omit the pronoun in the last one unless you were stressing that it's you who's travelling (as in "yo vuelo a las 10, no sé a qué hora vuelas tú").

I'd go with "Mi vuelo es a las 10" in most situations.

Comment: @belisarius. No sé, a mí no me suena raro para nada, por eso puse eso en la respuesta.

Answer (score 4):

also consider using the verb **despegar** (to take off). I hear this verb a lot.

> Mi vuelo / el avión despega a las 10

Comment: "Despegar" is "to take off". "Salir", in this context, would refer to leaving the gate. The times listed in the schedules are generally gate departure times. Actual take off is generally about 20 minutes later, or more, depending on tarmac waiting times and the size of the airfield.

Answer (score 3):

All of these are correct:

> Mi vuelo es a las 10.
>
> Mi vuelo sale a las 10.

This doesn't sound right:

> Yo vuelo a las 10.

Sounds better:

> Mi avión sale a las 10.

Comment: I find "Yo vuelo a las 10." absolute OK.

Answer (score 3):

"Partir" is another word you should consider.

> Mi vuelo parte a las 10.

Answer (score 2):

Mi vuelo es a las 10 ó Mi vuelo sale a las 10 are correct if you are a passenger
Yo vuelo a las 10 is mostly used if you are a pilot (or superman) it implies that you can actually fly by yourself (with or without any device/vehicle), it is also correct but will sound strange if you are a passenger.

Answer (score 1):

As spaniard, i can say i use all of them, except the second:
Mi vuelo está a las 10. Don' use this one.

@Walter As a passenger is very ok to say: Vuelo a las 10

Most commonly, it's said "Mi vuelo es a las 10"

So, mi vuelo es a las 10, y tengo que estar dos horas antes... :-)